# Conversão C++ para PHP

Tags: php, c++

Na conversão de um código em linguagens como C++ e outras afins para PHP temos que converter a manipulação direta dos ponteiros, neste caso, qual a interpretação que devo ter sobre o seguinte código:

```
long teste(unsigned char *lpMemIn ,unsigned char *lpMemOut, unsigned int uiBitComp,int bPartial,long Max){

    lpbData = &lpMemIn[0];

     while(lIndex < lNbrByte) {
        ...
        *(lpbData++) = ( lpbBuf[0]<<1 ) | ( lpbBuf[1]>>6 );
        ...
    }
}
```

Seria o mesmo que `arr[i++] = x | y;`?

Comment: Não consigo ter ideia do que exatamente o teu código `C++` faz, poderia adicionar o código completo?

Comment: Falta a variável `lpbBuf`

Comment: Acho que falta uma breve explicação do que o seu algorítimo em C++ faz, as vezes em outras linguagens podemos obter o mesmo resultado utilizando técnicas diferentes. Por exemplo, quem entende muito de PHP e nada de C++, dificilmente vai entender o que isso `*(lpbData++) = ( lpbBuf[0]<<1 ) | ( lpbBuf[1]>>6 );` faz